# Shipping a cross platform desktop application

Tags: linux, installation, desktop-application

We are trying to ship a cross platform desktop application to the 3 major platforms (Windows, MacOSX and Linux). On windows, distribution is very common through an exe installer and a dmg on MacOSX. My question is, what to distribute on Linux?

I've seen companies distributing .sh binaries. Is that the best way to ship for Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some companies, like Mozilla, distribute one tar.gz per architecture:

- large, statically linked,
- not updatable by standard tools,
- hard to maintain centrally (in an organization),
- dead easy to install
- simple to release.

Other companies, like Google, distribute multiple package formats, or at least .rpm and .deb, aimed at major versions of major distributions.

- compact, common dependencies are handled by package manager,
- uses standard package manager, can be easily centrally maintained,
- needs privileges to install,
- needs to closely watch compatibility with supported disto releases,
- needs complex packaging infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Although .rpm and .deb packages are the standard for many
Linux distributions, as mentioned by 9000, you would be forced to
 maintain multiple formats and also worry about differences in
 different versions of the package managers. For example, RPM packages
 targeting 4.x won't work on 3.x:

http://fedora.linuxsir.org/fedoradocs/rpm-guide/en/ch-rpm-evolution.html

and in many cases the way RPM dependencies between distributions are quite big.
 If your application is a popular open source app, then it is less of
 an issue, because distribution maintainers will take care of creating
 packages for it. Things change if you are a commercial or closed
 source company, in particular if you also need to support Windows and
 OS X

Sometimes it is more convenient to have a single installer that will
work on top of different Linux distributions or in some cases you need more
flexibility when asking required information to your end user before
 the actual installation of your application. The shell scripts used by
 some companies (internally packing a tar.gz) may workaround this
 limitation of the native packages but are still very limited in its UI
 and very complex to maintain (most of the logic must be included in
 the shell script, must be portable among different shells...). They
 also require pre-unpacking the bundled tar.gz.

There are some tools that allow creating binary executable installer,
 independent of the Linux version and highly customizable. These tools
have the advantages of being easier to maintain and install but
 depending on the tool may require some prerequisites in the target
 machine such as Java.

You could try our [BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) (disclaimer, I'm one of the
 developers), that creates binary installers that run in any Linux
 version without any external dependencies or pre-requisites. The
 generated installers add a minimal size overhead to the packed files
 and are really easy to customize. Also, the same project file can be
 shared to generate multiple platforms so you could have the three
 platforms with very little incremental work. We also support
 generating .rpm and .deb packages but as mentioned above you would
lose flexibility. I want to note that we offer free licenses for open
 source projects.